# Laravel eager load clients for a job

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I'm really struggling with how eager loading works with Laravel (Laravel 9), I have a page which is creating an N+1 box telling me I need to eager load clients. What I'm trying to do is get all open jobs belonging to a user and to show the clients title for each job (plus other data) Now i have client in my Job class (eloquent model):

```
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne( Client::class, 'id', 'client_id' );
    }
```

I have also a relationship in my User class to get jobs belonging to a user:

```
    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Job::class, // TargetTable
            JobUser::class, // Intermediate table
            'user_id', // Foreign key on intermediate table for current table
            'number', // Foreign key on target table to intermediate table
            'id', // Local key on current table used by intermediate table
            'job_number' // Local key on intermediate table to target table
        );
    }
```

So from the relevant controller I get a collection of all my jobs with this:

```
public function getPlannerData()
{
    $data = array();

    $myJobs =  = auth()->user()->jobs()->where( 'is_active', 1 )->get();
    $data['jobs'] = $myJobs;

    return $data;
}
```

this is put into an array and passed to the view

```
    /**
     * Display listing of the resource
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function index( Request $request )
    {
        return View::make( 'pages.planner.index' )
            ->with( 'data', Planner::getplannerData() );
    }
```

and finally in a component in my view I have the following while looping over the jobs:

```
<h1 class="text-xl text-gray-100">Client: {{ $item->job->client->title }}</h1>
```

So i have tried adding with('client') (and also with('App\Models\Client')) to in all of these but i still get the message (or i get no data).

So how do i eager load clients for the jobs in this collection so I do not get the message?

There is no issue with the code in that it does work and lists all the jobs with the clients titles but If I can optimise it and remove the N+1 message then that would be very useful!

I also have the N+1 issue on other pages so what I need is a thorough understanding on how this should work and how to resolve these issues.

Lastly I do have some pages where I have resolved the eager loading issues but these are more inline with what it says in the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `$jobs = Job::with('client')->where('is_active', 1)->get();` but I wish to get jobs belonging to a user and not all jobs (the users of the job are in a JobUsers table).

Can anyone help remove the mist and shed some light on how this should be done?

thanks

*** EDIT ***

thanks to Tim Lewis's suggestions, I've updated the question. The line above is actually the wrong line! it should be `<h1 class="text-xl text-gray-100">Client: {{ $item->job->client->title }}</h1>` I've updated the question accordingly. I have tried adding ->with('client') after job() but i still get the N+1 message. I have missed a lot of the code as mostly it is not being used while i get this resolved, there is a lot of code in this aspect of the app but I will share it all if it would help!.

The $item is a result of `@foreach($data['jobs'] as $item` but maybe calling it job would be clearer with this. I have however removed the call to this in this component and I still have the same N+1 issue so it probably isn't the component after all (but I can't think where else i would be using a job title on this page - it lists the jobs with the client names and nothing much else (bar the job description and status flags which are in the Job record).

Comment: `auth()->user()->jobs()->with('client')->where('is_active', 1)->get()` is how you would eager-load the `Job` model records with their associated `Client`, constrained to the currently authenticated `User`. That being said, if you're just doing `{{ $item->job->title }}`, that isn't referencing the `Client` relationship at all... That would be something like `$item->job->client->name` (although I'm a little unsure what `$item` is since you aren't showing that). Are you sure this is the code that is triggering that Eager Load warning?

Comment: HI Tim, please see my updated question with some additional notes

Comment: Gotcha! That all makes sense, and thanks for clarifying what `$item` is. You're right, it's not the best variable name for it, `$job` would likely be better, but then your code would be `$job->job->client->title`, which also seems odd. Does your code work if you did `$job->client->title`? (and `$job->title` instead of `$item->job->title`). Beyond that, I don't see why this would cause an N+1 query issue. What is generating that warning? Is it a `Debugbar` or something similar? It _might_ be a false-positive (which I've seen with that before)

Comment: Hi Tim, yes it is from laravel debugbar. Page is loading pretty quick but it is loading 31 clients (there aren't even 31 jobs) and the call as a query for client is called multiple times. It might be I can live with it. I'll try using the alternative suggestions and let you know.

Comment: Sounds good! Does Debugbar have N+1 query detection built in now? IIRC, the last time I used it, N+1 was an additional plugin that I ended up disabling. Nowadays, I rely on the "Queries" tab, and it's useful "X queries were duplicated" messaging to help track them down.

Comment: Can't say for definite as I also use telescope but I presume it did, I haven't extended it. if i use $item->client->title i get ```Undefined property: stdClass::$client``` Appreciate the help Tim, I'm going to simplify it on a new route so I can test it better and hopefully find the reason.